# ScrollView Messes Up Everything on Phone Screen

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I've been having this problem with the scrollview on Android phone screens. My layout looks like as I want it to be on a tablet screen. However, when switch it to a phone screen on my editor (also install the app on my phone), I get squeezed image buttons.

Here's how it looks like on phone: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5W7k4.jpg

My XML code is below. I've read that I might need to create another layout of image buttons with different dpis but I want to know if there is a way to do this without that.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="4"
    android:background="@drawable/pattern">

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/APUButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/APUButtonDescr"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/apu" />

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/LMSButton"
            android:contentDescription="@string/LMSButtonDescr"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/lms"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/mailButton"
            android:contentDescription="@string/mailButtonDescr"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/mail"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/scaButton"
            android:contentDescription="@string/SCAButtonDescr"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/sca"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/libButton"
            android:contentDescription="@string/libButtonDescr"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/library"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ratingButton"
            android:contentDescription="@string/ratingButtonDescr"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/rating"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/curricularButton"
            android:contentDescription="@string/curricularButtonDescr"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/curricular"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/aboutButton"
            android:contentDescription="@string/settingsButtonDescr"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/about"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: You might try changing the ImageButtons' `scaleType`s. `fitCenter` might do what you want.

Comment: they are getting "squeezed" because you are making the image `fitXY` and on a tablet the width of the column is bigger because there is more room. On a phone however the column width shrinks to fir the number of specified columns on the screen

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers. However, I'm still getting the long buttons after I change the fitXYs to fitCenter. So, there's a huge gap between the button rows. Is it also possible to fix that also? All I want is unified square image buttons :)

Comment: you are stretching you image to be the parents height also with `match_parent` which will also cause the squeeged look since the height of the cell is bigger than the width of the cell